# Why does my MySql query run twice?

Tags: php, mysql

I got a page which is URLRewrited by the .htaccess which runs a MySQL query twice eventhough I place it once, no loops no nothing.

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^go/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ /go.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^go/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ /$2.php?id=$1%{QUERY_STRING}
```

go.php

```
<?php
$update = mysql_query('UPDATE table SET page_views=page_views+1 WHERE id =123');
?>
```

Every time i refresh the page it adds 2 page views to the database, why is this?

Comment: can you add code

Comment: Post your entire `.htaccess`, and the relevant PHP code (or all of it).

Comment: code please! otherwise we have no idea why it's happening!!!

Comment: 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 comment votes. :o

Comment: Do you have any rule which would result in a request to favicon.ico being rewritten to go.php? The browser will request that file on each request (resulting in 2 requests per page load) if a favorite-icon is not found.

Comment: nope, the favicon is working fine but you got a point i'll check the page again

Comment: Check your access logs, is the page called once or twice?

Comment: @kornesh: have you looked at your access.log?

Comment: the problem is not with the htaccess i guess i tired to request page by go.php?id=123 it still adds the page_views twice

Comment: @kornesh: what about access.log?

Comment: 145.164.556.155 - - [24/Jan/2011:19:46:21 -0600] "GET /go.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1" 200 15113 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 AlexaToolbar/alxf-1.54 Firefox/3.6.13"

Comment: or here is the url to page http://www.exootlab.com/play/bouncing-balls notice the 'Plays'

Comment: Have you watched the request from an empty cache with Firefox Live HTTP Headers (or similar tool)?  My guess would be a JS, CSS, or image file that is matching the second rule.  Did you try commenting out both rules and using your direct URL?

Comment: That second rewrite rule does not look overly safe/sensible to me.  Arbitrary file execution.

Comment: @MPD i tired but its just the same. I have my JSS CSS and images files on subdomains so i dont think that would be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is whatever generates the RSS feed calling that function too?

I had a similar problem with Wordpress plugin dev before. Firefox does some sort of prefetch of the RSS, that causes 2 requests somehow..

**Edit**: The above didn't work. Do you have xdebug enabled? Use [xdebug_get_function_stack](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions#xdebug_get_function_stack) to see what paths are followed to get to your query.

Comment: @kornesh. Yes, but as I said, some browsers will automatically fetch the RSS linked in the header, without you even interacting with the RSS icon. That could cause 2 requests. Turn the RSS off in the header and see if your problem persists.

Comment: @kornesh. Added some alternative debug solution to my answer

Comment: I would start stripping some of your code out and simplify the request so it's easier to see where your problem is..

Answer (score 2):

It's a Browser Problem ;) Try with IE it will not Run Twice.

If you use Firefox Disable All Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your HTML submitting the script twice. example below worked for me

```
if($POST){
  $update = mysql_query('UPDATE table SET page_views=page_views+1 WHERE id =123');
 }
```

OR you can use GET to validate.